# Sharepoint Download file CSOM - last step

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell

Ok, so this maybe more PowerShell related than SharePoint. Actually, I am looking for the last step of downloading a file:

```
Write-Host "Load file ..."
$file = $ctx.Web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl($Source)
$ctx.Load($file)
$ctx.ExecuteQuery()
```

So, I have the $file object, that is a `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientObject`, how can I get it? I intentionally do not use PnP. Thank you.

Comment: This might help you: https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2018/08/sharepoint-online-powershell-to-get-file.html

Comment: Nope, these all end up the same place where my code. Finally figured out that I can pass this object to a stream. Looks messy, but it works.

Comment: Ok, that's cool :)

Comment: Could you provide your solution so that other can refer your experience?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@vilmarci,

Please take a reference of below cmdlets to download a file:

```
#Set parameter values
$SourceFile="/sites/s01/My test doc lib/license.txt"  #Relative URL
$TargetFile="D:\license.txt"

#sharepoint online powershell download file from library
$FileInfo = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File]::OpenBinaryDirect($ctx,$SourceFile)
$WriteStream = [System.IO.File]::Open($TargetFile,[System.IO.FileMode]::Create)
$FileInfo.Stream.CopyTo($WriteStream)
$WriteStream.Close()
```

Reference:

- https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-csom/ee537083(v=office.15)

BR